# Find the facility with the longest interval without accidents using Apache Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the next dataset:

```
|facility|date      |accidents|
| foo    |2019-01-01|1        |
| foo    |2019-01-02|null     |
| foo    |2019-01-03|null     |
| foo    |2019-01-04|2        |
| bar    |2019-01-01|1        |
| bar    |2019-01-02|null     |
| bar    |2019-01-03|3        |
```

And the goal is to find a facility with the longest continuous period of time without accidents:

```
|facility|startDate |interval|
|foo     |2019-01-02|2       |
```

Is it possible to do this using Spark SQL? Thanks

P.S. Code sample:

```
case class FacilityRecord(name: String, date: java.sql.Date, accidents: Option[Int])
case class IntervalWithoutAccidents(name: String, startDate: java.sql.Date, interval: Int)

implicit val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("Test")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val facilityRecords = Seq(
  FacilityRecord("foo", Date.valueOf("2019-01-01"), Some(1)),
  FacilityRecord("foo", Date.valueOf("2019-01-02"), None),
  FacilityRecord("foo", Date.valueOf("2019-01-03"), None),
  FacilityRecord("foo", Date.valueOf("2019-01-04"), Some(2)),
  FacilityRecord("bar", Date.valueOf("2019-01-01"), Some(1)),
  FacilityRecord("bar", Date.valueOf("2019-01-02"), None),
  FacilityRecord("bar", Date.valueOf("2019-01-03"), Some(3))
)

val facilityRecordsDataset = spark.createDataset(facilityRecords)

facilityRecordsDataset.show()

val intervalWithoutAccidents: IntervalWithoutAccidents = ??? // TODO: find the interval
val expectedInterval = IntervalWithoutAccidents("foo", startDate = Date.valueOf("2019-01-02"), interval = 2)
assert(expectedInterval == intervalWithoutAccidents)

println(intervalWithoutAccidents)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I filtered out records without accidents at all, grouped the rest by facility and collected dates in the list, then converted from DataFrame to DataSet and used the `map` function over records

`map { record => record.dates.sliding( ... ).foldLeft(...)` to find the longest interval without accidents for each record, and then sorted and picked the one. But I believe it could be done more efficiently

Comment: Can you create a minimal, reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added a code sample

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a 2-step approach:

1. Create column `accident_date` and for each `facility` compute `interval` value in every row between the current date and the next accident date using Window function `first`.
2. Compute the `max interval` per `facility` using Window function `max` and filter for the rows that have the max interval value.

Example code below:

```
import java.sql.Date
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("foo", Date.valueOf("2019-01-01"), Some(1)),
  ("foo", Date.valueOf("2019-01-02"), None),
  ("foo", Date.valueOf("2019-01-03"), None),
  ("foo", Date.valueOf("2019-01-04"), Some(2)),
  ("bar", Date.valueOf("2019-01-01"), Some(1)),
  ("bar", Date.valueOf("2019-01-02"), None),
  ("bar", Date.valueOf("2019-01-03"), Some(3))
).toDF("facility", "date", "accidents")

val win = Window.partitionBy($"facility").orderBy($"date").
  rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)
```

Step #1: Compute `interval`

```
val df2 = df.
  withColumn("accident_date", when($"accidents".isNotNull, $"date")).
  withColumn("interval",
    datediff(first($"accident_date", ignoreNulls=true).over(win), $"date")
  )

df2.show
// +--------+----------+---------+-------------+--------+
// |facility|      date|accidents|accident_date|interval|
// +--------+----------+---------+-------------+--------+
// |     bar|2019-01-01|        1|   2019-01-01|       0|
// |     bar|2019-01-02|     null|         null|       1|
// |     bar|2019-01-03|        3|   2019-01-03|       0|
// |     foo|2019-01-01|        1|   2019-01-01|       0|
// |     foo|2019-01-02|     null|         null|       2|
// |     foo|2019-01-03|     null|         null|       1|
// |     foo|2019-01-04|        2|   2019-01-04|       0|
// +--------+----------+---------+-------------+--------+
```

Step #2: Compute `max interval`

```
df2.select($"facility", $"date".as("start_date"),
    max($"interval").over(Window.partitionBy($"facility")).as("max_interval")
  ).
  where($"interval" === $"max_interval").
  show
// +--------+----------+------------+
// |facility|start_date|max_interval|
// +--------+----------+------------+
// |     bar|2019-01-02|           1|
// |     foo|2019-01-02|           2|
// +--------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Is there a way to add `startDate` column to the output as well?

Comment: @Alexey Sirenko, my bad, didn't notice that you also want the `date` column in the output.  Please see revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can derive this just with **One-step **SQL analytics function **lag()over(Window) and first_value()over(window)**.
Here is the code (added one extra test where 'foo' had another accident on `"2019-01-05"` and also `no-accident` on `"2019-01-06"`)

```
  val accidentDf = Seq(
    ("foo", Date.valueOf("2019-01-01"), Some(1)),
    ("foo", Date.valueOf("2019-01-02"), None),
    ("foo", Date.valueOf("2019-01-03"), None),
    ("foo", Date.valueOf("2019-01-04"), Some(2)),
    ("bar", Date.valueOf("2019-01-01"), Some(1)),
    ("bar", Date.valueOf("2019-01-02"), None),
    ("bar", Date.valueOf("2019-01-03"), Some(3)),
    ("foo", Date.valueOf("2019-01-05"), Some(3)),
    ("foo", Date.valueOf("2019-01-06"), None)
    ).toDF("facility", "date", "accidents")


    accidentDf.createOrReplaceTempView("accident_table")
```

now we  try to find for a particular row in a `facility` partition when did the **last accident** happened . If no accident happened then we keep the `last_accident_report_date`  as `first_value` else call the `date` in the row as when the accident happened

Then we see for each rows what is the `datediff` on `date` and last row's `last_accident_report_date`

Then we select where `datediff` is highest.

Here is the query

```
    val sparkSql="""select facility,date,accidents , 
            lag(CASE 
            WHEN accidents  is NULL 
            then first(date) over(partition by facility order by date) 
            else date  END ,1) 
            over(partition by facility order by date) as last_accident_report_date , 
            datediff(date, 
            lag(CASE WHEN accidents  is NULL then first(date) 
            over(partition by facility order by date) else date  END ,1) 
            over(partition by facility order by date)) 
            as no_accident_days_rank from accident_table order by no_accident_days_rank desc, facility"""
```

**RESULT**

```
                scala> spark.sql(sparkSql).show(20,false)
+--------+----------+---------+-------------------------+---------------------+
|facility|date      |accidents|last_accident_report_date|no_accident_days_rank|
+--------+----------+---------+-------------------------+---------------------+
|foo     |2019-01-04|2        |2019-01-01               |3                    |
|bar     |2019-01-03|3        |2019-01-01               |2                    |
|foo     |2019-01-03|null     |2019-01-01               |2                    |
|bar     |2019-01-02|null     |2019-01-01               |1                    |
|foo     |2019-01-02|null     |2019-01-01               |1                    |
|foo     |2019-01-06|null     |2019-01-05               |1                    |
|foo     |2019-01-05|3        |2019-01-04               |1                    |
|bar     |2019-01-01|1        |null                     |null                 |
|foo     |2019-01-01|1        |null                     |null                 |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------------------+---------------------+
```